# Updating PostgreSQL application_name during the client session

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to associate slow queries on PostgreSQL to applications that cause them. I have set rudimentary [application_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685861/setting-application-name-on-postgres-sqlalchemy) tracking.

Some applications contain several independent tasks running concurrently. Would it be possible to update `application_name` in the middle of a session to reflect the task the connection is currently processing? This way pinning down the source of problematic queries would be easier, as I could read from `pg_stat_activity` directly something human-readable for the root cause of slow queries.

(Alternative I can make clients to reconnect with different name, but this is a bit painful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testdb=# set application_name='myapp_pid12345';
SET
testdb=# select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid=pg_backend_pid();
 application_name 
------------------
 myapp_pid12345
(1 row)

testdb=# set application_name='myapp_pid54321';
SET
testdb=# select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid=pg_backend_pid();
 application_name 
------------------
 myapp_pid54321
(1 row)
```